# What should I do when a hacker gives me hacked money?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was peacefully playing GTA Online (yeah, was killing someone coming out of ls customs) then a hacker came and killed me using explosive ammos, I called him a hacker and he teleported to me and gave me 790k. I know that people get banned for receiving this kind of money, what should I do to avoid the ban?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ended up calling Rockstar and they removed the money. They said that I *might* get banned on the next banwave, and they also said that they left a note on my account so if I get banned I should call Rockstar again, and they will lift the ban. I also acted fast by [uploading a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIhf96ooh_8) and sending it to Rockstar.

Comment: Good advice for everyone

Comment: This is a joke man... All the hackers will start giving away money to increase the amount of people that "look like them". They should somehow be able to see who is "generating" this money and remove it, rather than banning the players that didn't cheat or something. If one spent all that money, he/she should just have a negative balance to compensate that.

Comment: Got money again, called again, got once more, called once more... GOT ONCE MORE (50m), got bored and spent it all. Will report if I get banned.

Comment: Reporting 2 months later: I got more money. I spent some of it. It didn't get removed, I didn't get banned.

Comment: 4 months later: Still not banned, and I now have a yacht!

Comment: 4 years later. Still not banned yet.

Answer (score 9):

Hmm, that's a different response to when it happened to me last year on the 360.

Basically Rockstar support told me to not worry about it, play as normal, and they'll remove the money when they get around to it. I never got banned.

I've just been given money for the second time but now on the PC version and for that reason I'm just not worried about it. If they do ban me though (I mean, I received the money, I didn't even ask for it) then I'll just point them to my first support ticket with them!

This is the reply to the original ticket, note the second to last paragraph:

> You are receiving this automatic ticket update because you have an open ticket in the Rockstar Support system related to GTA Online modding, cheating, or hacking. We have received a large number of complaints over the past few weeks about cheaters gifting large amounts of GTA$ to others, setting bounty rewards outside game limits, or otherwise attempting to tamper with the GTA Online economy.
>
> We have deployed several hotfixes to prevent this type of activity, and will be adding further cheat protection in future Title Updates as well. Players who willingly cheated to create this illegitimate influx of in-game currency have been separated out from the rest of the population and we are continuing to monitor for suspicious activity. If you were the unwilling recipient of an impossibly large amount of GTA$, you do not need to worry about us taking action against your account. However, please be aware that we will be making community-wide automatic adjustments to players’ account balances to remove the modded money.
>
> **At this time, you do not need to do anything further and this ticket will resolve on its own. Thank you for contacting us to report this activity. We look forward to seeing you Online!**
>
> If you believe you are receiving this message in error, or your ticket is not about GTA Online cheaters, please feel free to respond to this message and we will address your issue individually. Please note that we are not currently accepting appeals for players banned or in the Cheater Pool for transferring modded cash to others, and we are not able to remove these cash gifts on a case-by-case basis. Account balance adjustments will occur system-wide to undo these gifts.
>
> Rockstar Games

Answer (score 2):

You will **not** be banned for receiving hacked money. As per the Rockstar Games Customer Support article (updated 2017-11-30), [Update on GTA Online Cheaters and Modded GTA$](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/201617423/Update-on-GTA-Online-Cheaters-and-Modded-GTA) (emphasis mine):

> Question: I heard GTA Online cheaters were causing large amounts of
> modded GTA$ to transfer to innocent players over the past few weeks.
> Is Rockstar Games aware of this, and what is being done?
>
> Answer: We have received complaints over the past few weeks about
> cheaters gifting large amounts of GTA$ to others, setting bounty
> rewards outside game limits, or otherwise attempting to tamper with
> the GTA Online economy. We have deployed several hotfixes to prevent
> this type of activity, and will be adding further cheat protection in
> future Title Updates as well. Players who willingly cheated to create
> this illegitimate influx of in-game currency will be separated out
> from the rest of the population. **If you were the unwilling recipient
> of an impossibly large amount of GTA$, you do not need to worry about
> disciplinary action against your account.** However, please be aware
> that we will be making community-wide automatic adjustments to
> players’ account balances to remove the modded money.
>
> Question: I was minding my own business and suddenly received a huge
> amount of money in GTA Online from a cheater. Am I in trouble?
>
> Answer:
> To keep the gameplay environment as fair as possible for legitimate
> players, we routinely do sweeps to separate out cheaters and modders,
> and to reverse any illegitimate transactions. These sweeps are based
> on in-game automated detection, examination of suspicious gameplay
> statistics, and also manually-reviewed evidence submitted by the
> Community. **If you were not engaged in any willful cheating or
> exploiting yourself, you do not need to worry about getting caught up
> in our work to separate out cheaters from the rest of the population.**
>
> Question: Do I need to report to Rockstar Games the fact that I was
> given a huge amount of modded money I didn’t want?
>
> Answer: **No, you do
> not need to report this. We are able to tell the difference,
> automatically through gameplay data, between the cheaters and the
> players who received this money innocently.** Players who were willingly
> cheating are notified about any action taken against their account. If
> you were not cheating, you do not need to do anything further.

Comment: You can also spend the money if you wish to: "If you already spent some or all of the modded money you were given, you may find that your account balance after adjustment is lower than it was before you received the counterfeit money - this is correct as you will be allowed to keep the items you bought."

Answer (score 0):

The process is they ban the hacker and remove any money they created and sent. They do not take items from you or ban someone who just received money without asking for it. If they can see that you were asking for money then you get banned too. If you spend it fast and don't talk to the hacker you are fine and get to have free stuff, if that's what you want or just don't spend it an wait for it to disappear...

Comment: Thing is, I work(ed) hard in GTA:O, and now I have everything in game. Best cars (all upgraded and gold), best apts, all clothing, all guns, everything. It is not fun anymore. Do not spend hacked money, or you will take away fun times of grinding too.